# How do I do a where clause on a column on an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models: `Connection` and `Membership`...that have the following associations between them:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inviter, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
  belongs_to :invited, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "invited_id"
  has_many :connections, dependent: :destroy
end

class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inviter_membership, class_name: "Membership", foreign_key: "membership_id"
  belongs_to :invited_membership, class_name: "Membership", foreign_key: "invited_membership_id"    
end
```

Here are two `membership` objects:

```
[34] pry(#<Membership>)> self
=> #<Membership id: 54, family_tree_id: 43, user_id: 41, created_at: "2015-12-01 00:40:37", updated_at: "2015-12-01 00:40:37", relation: "wife", member_id: nil, invited_id: 1, relative_type: 0>
[35] pry(#<Membership>)> mem
=> #<Membership id: 53, family_tree_id: 1, user_id: 1, created_at: "2015-12-01 00:39:58", updated_at: "2015-12-01 00:40:37", relation: "husband", member_id: nil, invited_id: 41, relative_type: 0>
[39] pry(#<Membership>)> self.invited_id
=> 1
```

Then I have a `connection` object:

```
[36] pry(#<Membership>)> c
=> #<Connection id: 38, membership_id: 53, sent_at: "2015-12-01 00:40:14", responded_at: nil, send_limit: nil, times_sent: 1, removed_at: nil, created_at: "2015-12-01 00:40:14", updated_at: "2015-12-01 00:40:14", request_status: 0, invited_membership_id: nil>
```

How do I find all the `connection` records, that have `membership.invited_id = 41` (or some value)?

In other words, I would like to do something like this:

```
Connection.where("membership.invited_id = ? OR invited_membership.invited_id = ?", self.id, self.id).exists?
```

But when I try the above, I get this error:

```
[138] pry(main)> Connection.where("membership.invited_id = ? OR invited_membership.invited_id = ?", 41, 41).exists?
  Connection Exists (165.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "connections"  WHERE (membership.invited_id = 41 OR invited_membership.invited_id = 41) LIMIT 1
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "membership"
LINE 1: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "connections"  WHERE (membership.invit...
```

So how do I run a `where` query to match the column of an associated record with the parameter that I supply?

**Edit 1**

Based on the wonderful suggestion from @messanjah I am almost there. This is the query I am using:

```
Connection.joins(:inviter_membership, :invited_membership).
      where("memberships.invited_id = ? OR invited_memberships_connections.invited_id = ? OR memberships.user_id = ? OR invited_memberships_connections.user_id = ?", self.inviter.try(:id), self.inviter.try(:id), self.invited.try(:id), self.invited.try(:id)).exists?
```

Where `self` is this:

```
[22] pry(#<Membership>)> self
=> #<Membership id: 69, family_tree_id: 49, user_id: 47, created_at: "2015-12-01 04:53:17", updated_at: "2015-12-01 04:53:17", relation: "wife", member_id: nil, invited_id: 1, relative_type: 0>
```

But when I run that query, it returns an empty array or `false`:

```
[14] pry(#<Membership>)> connection_exists
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "connections" INNER JOIN "memberships" ON "memberships"."id" = "connections"."membership_id" INNER JOIN "memberships" "invited_memberships_connections" ON "invited_memberships_connections"."id" = "connections"."invited_membership_id" WHERE (memberships.invited_id = 47 OR invited_memberships_connections.invited_id = 47 OR memberships.user_id = 1 OR invited_memberships_connections.user_id = 1) LIMIT 1
=> false
```

Despite the fact that there is a `memberships` record with those IDs, as can be seen here:

```
[24] pry(#<Membership>)> c
=> #<Connection id: 49, membership_id: 68, sent_at: "2015-12-01 04:52:51", responded_at: nil, send_limit: nil, times_sent: 1, removed_at: nil, created_at: "2015-12-01 04:52:51", updated_at: "2015-12-01 04:52:51", request_status: 0, invited_membership_id: nil>
[25] pry(#<Membership>)> c.inviter_membership
=> #<Membership id: 68, family_tree_id: 1, user_id: 1, created_at: "2015-12-01 04:52:32", updated_at: "2015-12-01 04:53:17", relation: "husband", member_id: nil, invited_id: 47, relative_type: 0>
[26] pry(#<Membership>)> c.invited_membership
=> nil
[27] pry(#<Membership>)> c.inviter_membership.invited_id
=> 47
[28] pry(#<Membership>)> c.inviter_membership.user_id
=> 1
```

Note the `IDs` returned in the last two queries, yet when passed in to the main query I ran it returned empty.

What could be causing this?

**Edit 2**

This is the new code I am trying:

```
Connection.joins("LEFT JOIN memberships inviter_memberships ON inviter_memberships.id = connections.membership_id").
  joins("LEFT JOIN memberships invited_memberships ON invited_memberships.id = connections.invited_membership_id").
  where("inviter_memberships.invited_id = ? OR invited_memberships.invited_id = ?
  OR inviter_memberships.user_id = ? OR invited_memberships.user_id = ?", self.invited.try(:id), self.invited.try(:id), self.inviter.try(:id), self.inviter.try(:id)).exists?
```

Where `self` is:

```
[15] pry(#<Membership>)> self
=> #<Membership id: 71, family_tree_id: 50, user_id: 48, created_at: "2015-12-01 05:46:00", updated_at: "2015-12-01 05:46:00", relation: "wife", member_id: nil, invited_id: 1, relative_type: 0>
[20] pry(#<Membership>)> self.invited
=> #<User id: 1, email: "abc@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$IQXTVqZmMaUUv4WZlwXze.OTfWki2d2qZEjj01isCZZ...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 7, current_sign_in_at: "2015-09-25 09:35:43", last_sign_in_at: "2015-09-25 01:36:10", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "192.168.1.106", created_at: "2015-07-25 02:20:15", updated_at: "2015-09-25 09:35:43", first_name: "Marc", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2015-07-25 02:20:16", confirmation_sent_at: "2015-07-25 02:20:16", unconfirmed_email: nil, invitation_relation: nil, avatar: "Me-Bio-Pic.jpg", invitation_token: nil, invitation_created_at: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invited_by_type: nil, invitations_count: 0, bio: "I am Marc Gayle. I build things and I love my fami...", last_name: "Gayle", gender: 0, birthday: nil>
[21] pry(#<Membership>)> self.inviter
=> #<User id: 48, email: "def@test.com", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2015-12-01 05:40:45", updated_at: "2015-12-01 05:40:45", first_name: "Cheyenne-Kari", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, invitation_relation: "husband", avatar: nil, invitation_token: "D8uPGyxAeX95kfYGxRq-", invitation_created_at: "2015-12-01 05:40:45", invitation_sent_at: "2015-12-01 05:40:45", invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_id: 1, invited_by_type: "User", invitations_count: 0, bio: nil, last_name: "Gayle", gender: 1, birthday: nil>
```

Basically what I am trying to do is trying to discover whether a `connection` record exists for the related `membership` record I am about to create (in an effort to not create a duplicate `connection` record).

In other words, each `connection` record, should correspond to both an `inviter_membership` and an `invited_membership`.

Right now, the connection is being created on an `after_create :setup_connection` callback on the `Membership` model. So I am trying to check the database for a `Connection` record that has the related `membership` model and then just update that `connection` record rather than creating a new one.

So that's why the `self` in my code snippets, is a `membership` record (because I am debugging with pry during runtime -- i.e. after the `after_create` has been called and before the new `connection` record has been created).

I hope that helps to clarify what I am trying to do. If not, I can explain some more.

**Edit 3**

Here is the server logs from executing the `LEFT JOIN` SQL I did above:

```
[1] pry(#<Membership>)> connection_exists
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "connections" LEFT JOIN memberships inviter_memberships ON inviter_memberships.id = connections.membership_id LEFT JOIN memberships invited_memberships ON invited_memberships.id = connections.invited_membership_id WHERE (inviter_memberships.invited_id = 1 OR invited_memberships.invited_id = 1
      OR inviter_memberships.user_id = 51 OR invited_memberships.user_id = 51) LIMIT 1
=> false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join on the associations to include their columns in a `where`.

```
Connection.joins(:inviter_membership, :invited_membership).
  where("memberships.invited_id = ? OR invited_memberships_connections.invited_id = ?", self.id, self.id)
```

This is a little awkward because the table aliases are not obvious (I'm using Rails 4.2.3, YMMV).

You may wish to construct the joins explicitly, for greater control over the query:

```
Connection.
  joins("INNER JOIN memberships inviter_memberships ON inviter_memberships.id = connections.inviter_membership_id").
  joins("INNER JOIN memberships invited_memberships ON invited_memberships.id = connections.invited_membership_id").
  where("inviter_memberships.invited_id = ?
      OR invited_memberships.invited_id = ?", self.id, self.id)
```

If an association record may not exist (for example, a Connection may not have an invited_membership), use a LEFT join to avoid throwing it out.

```
Connection.
  joins("LEFT JOIN memberships inviter_memberships ON inviter_memberships.id = connections.inviter_membership_id").
  joins("LEFT JOIN memberships invited_memberships ON invited_memberships.id = connections.invited_membership_id").
  where("inviter_memberships.invited_id = ?
      OR invited_memberships.invited_id = ?", self.id, self.id)
```

Comment: Perfect...this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks much!

Comment: Almost perfect :) -- See updated question with more details about what's broken here @messanjah.

Comment: Probably one of the INNER joins threw out the record you wanted. Switch to LEFT joins.

Comment: I was actually using the Active Record query. Haven't tried the SQL one yet. What could be causing it in that version?

Comment: The same. ActiveRecord performs an INNER join when joining with that syntax. A LEFT join requires the string form.

Comment: Ahh ok. Lemme try that and see.

Comment: Nope...that doesn't work. I still get `false` even though I know for sure 1 record exists.

Comment: Please update the question to reflect the new code and unexpected results (including logger output).

Comment: Updated. I also added more context about what I am trying to achieve (i.e. the 'big picture') so you can more fully appreciate the context. Perhaps I am going about this in the wrong way? But I feel like your SQL is VERY close...just a matter of figuring out what the issue is.

Comment: The only other thing that could throw out your expected result is the WHERE clause. Please include the log output of executing the code with left joins.

Comment: I updated the question with the log output of executing that SQL.

Comment: I got it finally! It turns out the issue was that I was testing it against the wrong `id`. Instead of checking it against `self.invited.id` I should have been testing it against `self.inviter.id`. My bad. Thanks much!